# System.exit(num) or throw a RuntimeException from main?

Tags: java, exception, errorlevel

I've got a single threaded app that should set the DOS errorlevel to something non-zero if there is a problem. Is it better to throw a RuntimeException, or to use System.exit(nonzero)? I don't need the stack trace, and I don't expect this app to be extended/reused. What are the differences between these two options?

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question. If you have to set a DOS error code you have to use System.exit(code). You can't do that with an exception.

Comment: Thowing a RuntimeException from main sets errorlevel to 3, though I'm not sure why or if it's under all circumstances.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't throw an exception unless you really have an exceptional condition. `System.exit(int)` is there for precisely this reason. Use it.

**EDIT:** I think I may have misread your question. I thought you were asking, when you want to exit the JVM normally but signal that something did not quite go right, whether it is better to throw an exception or to use `System.exit`.

However, if the problem that occurs is something which is already indicated by a Java exception, it's fine to just let that exception go unhandled. You don't have to catch the exception and call `System.exit`.

If you have a choice of whether to throw an exception of your own or call `System.exit`, think about whether the error condition is something that might conceivably be handled by some Java code that calls your method. If the error occurs directly in the `main` method, then there will probably never be a caller to handle the exception so you should probably call `System.exit`. Otherwise, it's generally best to throw an exception - but not `RuntimeException`, you should probably use an exception type that appropriately represents the error you encountered. Write your own subclass of `RuntimeException` if necessary.

Comment: Then why do exceptions thrown from main set the errorlevel? It seems they are there for some reason.

Comment: When an application does not finish successfully, its return code should be something other than 0. So the JVM will automatically set the return code to 1 if there is an unhandled exception, so that the parent process knows that your program terminated because of an error (and not just because it finished working).

Answer (score 7):

Generally in this situation I would handle all exceptions in my main method, possibly by calling `System.exit`.  This gives you flexibility about where/whether/how to handle exceptional conditions, while still meeting your need to terminate with an error code. In particular, it gives you control over the return code and any other output you might generate for the user (error message, stack trace, etc). If you throw an exception in main (or let an exception escape), you lose that control.

To summarize, call `System.exit` only in your top-level exception handler:

```
static public void main() {
   try {
      runMyApp();
   } catch (Exception e) {
      System.exit(1);
   }
}
```

Comment: I'll probably go with this solution, but I was fishing for the reasons why System.exit is preferred over throwing an exception from main.

Answer (score 4):

An exception thrown will print out the stack trace, and if you don't need that, you shoul use System.exit.

Upon exit you can inform the user with a Sytem.out (I assume the app is running in a commanline environment only).

You should consider just catching all errors an logging the errors in a seperate log, this ensures the stacktrace is not lost forever when you close the terminal. Take a look at log4j for this purpose, it's really easy to use.

Comment: Yes, it's in a commandline environment only. I don't need the stack trace because it's an automated step in our build process that either passes or fails, so even log4j is overkill.

Comment: Then go for the system.exit solution. It's a good solution especially if you check the return code afterwards. That way you can signal what went wrong using different codes, or just go for System.exit(-1)

Answer (score 2):

The APP itself should use System.exit. It's its interface with the calling environment (script). Any internal component of course should use Exception. When you put it together it can be the both of'em:

```
Application.main(...) {
  parse(args);
  check(...);
  try {
    MyObject o = ...;
    o.doMyStuff();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println("Oops, something went wrong!"); // by example, or use a logging framework! // anyway in a shell app System.in/out/err IS my interface with the outworld
    System.exit(ERROR_CODE);
  }
  System.out.println("Worked!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends how much information you want to report back to the script that starts your program. This can be very important if the script is designed to execute a chain of actions. https://shapeshed.com/unix-exit-codes/

*Example*: I developed a Java program that calls an external API, downloads the response and saves it to a file.
Possible outcomes:

- 0 = OK
- 5 = HTTP Temporarily unavailable
- 6 = Unable to write file to disk

Now my script knows what went wrong, and it could take different actions based on the outcome.

- If response = 0, continue next step in the script
- If response = 5, retry (with a delay)
- If response = 6, stop the script

**Bottom line**: like any good api, clearly define your input and output parameters and use `System.exit`.

Answer (score -2):

System.exit(num) is not a good option, as its shutdown JVM, plus even it didnt run the finally block if you have after catch block.

Throwing RuntimeException also might not be the best of the option, can subclass as mentioned earlier which is app specific exception could be a better option in my opinion. 
-Manish

Answer (score -5):

System.exit() not recommended. It shutdowns JVM.

Comment: Shutting down the JVM is OK in this case, the application is done if there is an error.

Comment: neither generic RuntimeException is advised in my opinion

Comment: either system.exit(int) or throw new RuntimeException, isn't the latter considered a generic RuntimeException?

Comment: yes. Throwing RuntimeException is better compared to calling System.exit(int)

Comment: I generally agree with you. I was looking more for the "why" part, but there may not be advantages to either method in this case. I'm mostly worried that the errorlevel set from throwing an exception isn't consistent, but neither is the errorlevel set from System.Exit(num) because it can throw an exception itself.

Comment: I appreciate counter opinions, but please explain them.