# Swing: How to close JDialog programmatically from a controller?

Tags: java, swing

I've got a JDialog bound to my (separate) controller class via beans binding (Netbeans). My dialog has a "close" Button. The action property of this button is bound to an action in my controller.

Dialog:

```
public class AppVersionCheckDialog extends javax.swing.JDialog {
    ...
    binding = org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Bindings.createAutoBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, controller, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${closeButtonActionListener}"), btnOk, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BeanProperty.create("action"));
    bindingGroup.addBinding(binding);
    ...
}
```

So basically I got

```
public class AppVersionCheckDialogController extends AbstractController {

    private final Action closeAction = new AbstractAction("Close") {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // dialog.dispose() - no reference of dialog instance here 
        }
    };


    public Action getCloseButtonActionListener(){
        return closeAction;
    }
}
```

in my controller.

I do not have any reference to the dialog within the controller. And I don't want to introduce one, as it breaks the whole principle of binding things together.

So how to close the dialog? Is there a way to bind the dialog instance to a property of my controller? If so, how?

Comment: where dialog is defined ?

Comment: until now nowhere. I got two classes: The Dialog containing the controller as bean, and the controller which does not have any references to the dialog.

Comment: post your code please

Comment: The relevant code is show above. All other stuff is generated code by netbeans.

Comment: This is not a duplicate as I know how to close a dialog. The question is how to do this without directly referencing the dialog, and evading the beans binding principles

Comment: why you need this ?

Comment: Separation of concerns: The controller contains reusable logic (e.g. an action that closes a window), while the dialog class only contains UI stuff.

Comment: need your code of the controller at least

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to really close a JDialog with Java code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336161/how-to-really-close-a-jdialog-with-java-code)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't have a compiler with me now, but if I understand correctly what you want is similar to this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Component component = (Component) e.getSource();
        JDialog dialog = (JDialog) SwingUtilities.getRoot(component);
        dialog.dispose();
      }
```

I'll have a look when I have the chance to compile and if it has problems. I hope, it solves your problem.

Comment: The above solution is not equivalent to clicking the close window button. It does not run the event listener for windowClosing(...)